# Spring AOP - Execution coverage

Tags: spring-aop

To what classes (in which packages) and methods does this `execution` apply?

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation" expression="execution(* com.my.application.service..*Manager.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

I hade read about Spring AOP on http://spring.io/docs but can't understand the `execution` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spring docs 10.2.3 section in [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) it is quite clear and execution is used to designate a pointcut.

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern) throws-pattern?)
```

1. modifiers-pattern - Method visibility (public, protected, private, *)
   ret-type-pattern - Return type of the method
2. declaring-type-pattern - Package or class (ex: com.app.service.* - applies to all classes in this package, com.app.service.UserService - applies only to UserService class, * - all)
3. name-pattern - method name (ex: set* - all setters)
4. param-pattern - method parameters (.. - any number of parameters, java.lang.String - method taking String as parameter.
5. throws-pattern - Method throwing this exception.

In your case

```
expression="execution(* com.my.application.service..*Manager.*(..))"/>
```

you are designating this pointcut to all methods whose classname ends with Manager in com.my.application.service package & its sub-packages.